# how to get the primary or secondary email addresses programmatically in wp8?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

How can I get the primary or secondary email addresses configured on the device programmatically? I need to display the email addresses configured. Is that possible in windows phone? It is possible in android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible with the current API.